# Having trouble trying to access a class variable inside my shared method (JSON & VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, json, variables, shared

Inside my .aspx I have some JSON code that looks like this:

```
function someFunctionName() {
        var dataStuff = $.toJSON({
            someData: $("#someData").text(),
            someMoreData: $("#someMoreData").text()
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageName.aspx/doIt",
            data: dataStuff,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json"
        });
        document.location.href = 'PageName.aspx';
}
```

Basically what I'm doing is pulling text from two labels on one page, and sending them to another page by calling the "doIt" function which looks like this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub doIt(ByVal someData As String, ByVal someMoreData As String)
    MessageBox.Show("Successful execution!")
End Sub
```

Just so I'm clear, the "doIt" function and the JSON call are on two separate web forms. My problem is that with the "doIt" function being Shared, I can't access any global variables of the class. And if I remove the Shared, my JSON doesn't execute. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's appropriate, you could change the fields in your class (the "global variables", as you called them) to shared as well.  Then they will be accessible from shared methods.  However, that will mean their value will be shared among all instances of the class.  If that's what you want, though, that's your answer.

Comment: That's it! Sorry about the terminology. I'm a self taught programmer, never went to school for it so sometimes I trip up. Thanks!

Comment: @Stylzs05 No problem.  Self taught programmers are the best kind (me inclusive)!

Comment: Be sure to be careful with Shared/Global values when working with asp pages, mostly that those values are not supposed to be unique to a user or session. We had an instance where a database connection was in a shared/global variable. If two people clicked search at the same time, there was chance one would get the other ones results.